# jQuery AJAX timeout undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

I was trying out example jQuery examples and to my surprise, I got an error state for an AJAX call  mentioning that timeout isn't defined. When I removed timeout attribute, it worked fine.
I downloaded jQuery few days back, so I am pretty sure it's not a version problem.

I was trying with Firefox(3.6.8) and not any other browser.

Why would this occur?

**Edit**: Code snippet moved from the comments to the question

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "GET", 
  dataType: 'json', 
  url: PHPServiceProxy, 
  timeout: 5000, 
  success: function(reply) { } // note: original code snippet provided was missing a comma here.
  error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { } 
});
```

Comment: Can you put a snipset of code here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `timeout` property has been present in jQuery for a long time so I don't think that your problem is related to it. Maybe you have a syntax error in your code. This should work:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    url: PHPServiceProxy, 
    timeout: 5000, 
    success: function(reply) { 

    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

    } 
});
```

Comment: I have tried it couple of times and I too am surprised that it wasn't working. It was happening at my office PC. Well let me try that now and see if things are working.

Comment: Looks to work here at my PC. I guess you are right, must have missed out something.