# What is jQuery's ajax default timeout value?

Tags: jquery, timeout

Does anyone know what the default jQuery ajax timeout value is?

Comment: It seems it is undefined and left for the specific implementation in the browser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507355/jquery-ajax-call-default-timeout-value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394760/jquery-ajax-timeout-undefined

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The default is `0` ([technically it's undefined](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L277), but behaves as 0).  This means no timeout in jQuery itself...if the browser has some timeout it's entirely possible you'll hit that.

Only when a `timeout` option is specified [does jQuery even call `setTimeout()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L700).

Comment: my tests suggest erkmene, above, is actually right - the browser sets the timeout...

Comment: @hwjp - the line number in the source has changed in recent versions, but the answer above is still correct, note the `timeout > 0` check in jQuery itself: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L700 This isn't a question about raw `setTimeout(myFunc,0);`, it's about jQuery's `.ajax()` implementation when one's not specified.  The default is still `undefined`, but behaves like 0 in checks [as you can see here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L277).  The default **for jQuery** (what the question was asking) is still effectively 0.

Comment: Sure - I just think most people care more about what the effective timeout is.... So the best answer would say "by default the timeout is set by the browser" - followed by a technical explanation of whys + hows...

Comment: Another thing to note is that jQuery AJAX timeout only works if the "async" setting is set to true, which is by default.