# Setting the timeout when using Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, timeout, undefined, undefined-reference

I recently updated an app that uses Dojo to sent asynchronous petitions to my server which serves these petitions with cgi.

My problem is as follows. So for example the variable that makes the requests is

```
parent.sc_dojo.io.script.jsonp_sc_dojoIoScript2
```

This new service takes too long to send the response approximately 40 - 60 seconds, and after this time the variable parent.sc_dojo.io.script.jsonp_sc_dojoIoScript2 appears as UNDEFINED

I made an analysis using firebug, see the following image for major details.

[image: Petitions to my server responded in 40 to 50 secs]

The petition to the server has the following data:

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Date    Tue, 10 Sep 2013 12:39:22 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
```

The timeout ranges from 5 to 100, I don't really know the units of this measure, Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About Connection Keep-Alive**
When a client browser sends the "Connection: Keep-alive" header to an HTTP/1.1 server, the browser is saying "hey, I want to carry on a long conversation, so don't close the connection after the first exchange."

The keep-alive "timeout" value is in seconds.  The "max" value is unit-less, representing the maximum number of requests to service per connection.  Taken together, these augment the client's request to "hey, I want to carry on a long conversation, so don't close the connection after the first exchange BUT *if nothing exchanges in 5 seconds* (timeout) OR *if more than 100 requests go back and forth* (max), I'm ok with you closing the connection."  The server responds with the actual values it will service for timeout and max.

The penalty for a closed connection is that a new one has to be opened up.  Some modern browsers limit the number of simultaneous open connections, so keeping these values too small may introduce latency (while your app waits for free connections).  On the other hand, the server need not agree to the timeout and max values requested: the server sets its own limits.

See these articles for details:

- http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/keep-alive.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection
- http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/ange/archives/archives-95/http-wg-archive/1661.html

**About dojo timeouts**
I don't see your code or dojo version, but dojo does allow you to set how long it will wait for a response via [the timeout property in the XHR request](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html#id4).  The default timeout is "never".  Code below.

In practice, "never" is misleading: browsers have [their own defaults](http://gabenell.blogspot.com/2010/11/connection-keep-alive-timeouts-for.html) for keep-alive timeouts and [upstream routers might have their own timeouts](https://superuser.com/a/316453).

Try to keep it short. If the response takes more than 15 seconds, there may need to be [a different design approach to the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297833/how-long-will-the-browser-wait-after-an-ajax-request): reverse ajax, polling, combined response, etc.

```
require(['dojo/request/xhr'], function (xhr) {
  xhr(
    'http://www.example.com/echo',
    { timeout:15000 /* change this, units are milliseconds */, handleAs:'json' }
  ).then(function (r) {
    console.log(r);
  });
});
```

**The specific problem**
Ok, finally. If you have a long server side run, here's what I would do:

1. Send a request from client to server that starts the job
2. Server responds with a unique URL that can be polled for status
3. In Javascript, use setInterval() to periodically check the returned URL for status
4. When the URL shows "status" done, kill the setInterval and issue a final call to get the result