# AJAX launched PHP script terminating without good reason

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**I have a very simple PHP script:**

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 240000);

//Switch for terminating the test processing status loop
$completed = false; 

while ($completed == false) {
    sleep(2);
}
```

**This is launched using AJAX which is again, very simple:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "lib/check_processing_status.php",
    timeout: 0,
    async: true,
    error: function() {
        console.log("FAILURE");
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
    }
});
```

This script should run indefinitely, or at least until the timeout is triggered.  Yet it fails after a duration which differs each time it is run.  Sometimes just 40 seconds, sometimes 1 minute and 10 seconds.

Why is this failing!?

**Additional:**

Just to add some context, the reason I am having a loop like this, is because I will be querying a server for the progress of a process, so instead of calling loads of AJAX requests every 5 seconds (filling up the console window with 10's of requests), I figured it neater to stay inside the PHP script until the process is complete and then return when its complete.

Comment: Even if you set the ajax timeout to 0, your browser may not wait indefinitely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297833/how-long-will-the-browser-wait-after-an-ajax-request

Comment: Would you say the browser is terminating the php script?

Comment: Not the php script, the connection.

Comment: The connection will time-out after some time, you should add the while/sleep in the front-end instead of the back-end. So do a request, get a false as result and after some seconds do an other request.

Comment: Ironically that was how I originally coded it, but I wasn't happy with the many PHP requests in the console window for debugging purposes, so I changed it, I didn't realise browsers can kill an active connection.

Comment: What you are trying to do is similar to "long polling" in jQuery (similar problems may occur here). There are multiple articles about this out on the web

Comment: Ah indeed, I found this which is very informative:  https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Comment: The above is what I was doing the first time round, well, I've learnt something here, thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the browser was killing the PHP scripts connection, even though the script was configured not to time out for over an hour and was running as intended.  I assume the browser thought it was not functioning correctly.

This implies polling a server using a long running PHP script isn't really possible, you have to do it on the JavaScript side or consider a more involved **long polling** solution which is explained nicely here:

https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Big thanks to those in the comments of the question who answered this.